# Script should not process further If "Error" keyword found

Tags: jmeter

[image: **Snapshot**]

I am able to capture this "Error" keyword as shown in screenshot. But if check http request is showing as passed even though error has occurred. Is there a way via which if this "Error" keyword comes in any response data either request should get failed or script should not execute further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of your sampler.

Select in "Pattern Matching Rules"

- **Contains** (true if the text contains the regular expression pattern)
- **Not** (NOT may also be selected to invert the result of the check).

Then add one pattern "Error".